Issues with switch debouncing
I am having some issues with debouncing a switch with an RC filter and 74HC14 Schmitt-trigger inverter IC. I am using a standard circuit that is linked in the datasheet. The circuit in question here and here.
I am using the normal switch debounce circuit. The output LED is partially on when the button is not pressed, and the Schmitt-trigger has an output voltage of around 2V. When the button is pressed, the output voltages goes to about 2.7V. However, if I remove the capacitor the LED stays off until the button is pressed.
The circuits in question:

My question is why is the Schmitt-trigger output never 0V? The IC has a push-pull output, so the output does not need a pullup/pulldown.
Edit: when the capacitor is removed, the output has a normal range of 0V-5V. Also, if it matters, all unused inputs are tied directly to ground, just like the datasheet states.

There's something wrong somewhere. Bad (low resistance) capacitor or missing ground somewhere.

What is your Vcc? What are you using for the debounce capacitor?

@MathKeepsMeBusy VCC is 5V and the debounce cap is C2 - 100nF

Try a new chip. That one might be damaged from static.

@MOSFET the chip works, I am using another gate with no issue.

@Transistor I think you were right, I swapped the capacitor with another, and the circuit works fine. How would I test my capacitors to see if they are bad?

Yes, I was wondering if it is ceramic.

@MathKeepsMeBusy It is a ceramic. I also swapped it out with a .1uF electrolytic cap and it still worked. I just happened to use the only broken capacitor I had.

Electrolytics, if the have been left unused for a long time can leak current, which could cause your input to be low..

In my case, @Transistor was correct, in that the capacitor was bad. I switched it out with another, and the circuit works properly.

Good work. You should be able to "Accept" your own answer after a day or so. (I can't remember how long.)
